# Custom fonts dropping after page goes idle in Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, custom-font

I got fonts from fonts.com and uploaded them to our server (we are running a site in SiteCore). Everything was working smooth until about 2 months ago, I started noticing an issue in Chrome MAC and WIN. Here are the events:
Load a page with our fonts, switch to another Chrome tab, go idle, come back to the first page - now it looks like my custom fonts got dropped, and the page is displaying default fonts in place of custom. If I refresh the page - all goes back to normal.

I am linking to them from CSS via @font-face. Has anybody ran into this issue?

Comment: This question is not related to Sitecore, I think you can delete Sitecore tags

Comment: Here is the Chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this bug on several websites, I guess it'll be fixed in the next Chrome update.